# PHP/HTML Nested Navigation list giving unexpected results

Tags: php, html, recursion, navigation, nested

I'm writing a recursive navigation menu in PHP for easier organization and expandability. For now I am using some examples from Diablo II to get the nesting to work properly.

The recursive looping is giving me some weird results. Sometimes it only returns a single letter as opposed to the name/url of an array and it doesn't recurse through all elements.

It's a bit difficult to explain, and my main issue is I don't really understand how to debug this. It's probably something simple that I can't figure out.

To save everyone time, I made a page with the source (syntax highlighted) and output here:

http://radleygh.com/files/test/example.php

That should make it easy to see what is going on.

The layout of the list should look like this (With the name and UL of each group contained within the same LI element):

```
ul
  li 
    Parent Title #1
    ul
      li
        Child Title #1
      li 
        Child Title #2
    /ul
  li
    Parent Title #2
/ul
```

PS: Is there a better way to go about sorting a huge array like the one I have?

Thanks. Back to debugging for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. Where your mistake lies is within the `recurse_array` function. You are passing it elements of a *single dimension array* (I know that it is technically multiple dimensions given `$element[2]`, but the first two elements are single :)), so when it grabs that, it takes that the words are to be broken out into their own array.

Try this:

```
function recurse_array($element) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    echo "  <li>"."<a href='{$element[1]}'>{$element[0]}</a>\n";
    if (is_array($element[2])) {
        echo recurse_array($element[2]);
    }
    echo "  </li>\n";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

It should give you what you are looking for, or at least something a bit closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you meant, but I kept thinking about "single dimension array". And then I got it. My arrays third element was supposed to be ZERO or ARRAY. Due to the layout, my code was misleading. I listed multiple arrays for the third element, but I did not enclose the /list of arrays/ inside their own array() function! So it should have looked like $element[0][2] = Array(Array($name, $url, 0), Array($name, $url, 0)). Got it working now.